# "Argument of \@tempa has an extra }" problem in TeX Live 2019/Debian with svmono (Springer)

Tags: includegraphics, sv-classes

My Latex source of a large document was working perfectly in TeX Live 2017/Debian with Ubuntu 18.04, but when upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 and to pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian), the LaTeX no longer compiles, with the "`Argument of \@tempa has an extra }`" complaint after the first figure in the manuscript. But (fortunately) it continues to compile on another computer I have with the older Ubuntu 18.04/TexLive 2017, which has me confused as to the origin of the error.

The documentclass is `svmono`, since I am writing a new edition for a Springer book. I extracted a minimal working example below, with the class, style file and figure available [here](https://www.bonamente-statistics-data-analysis.com/home/downloads)

When compiling here is the problem:

`! Argument of \@tempa has an extra }`.

with the offending line identified as:

`l.21 {\caption{Caption} \label{caption} }`

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmono}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\usepackage[T1,S600print]{spbwftex-v4}% custom package for springer
\usepackage{amsmath}
Hi there

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.2in]{venn1.eps}
\caption{Caption \label{cap}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Seems to me that the problem is with the `\includegraphics` command, that somehow gets redefined in the class or style file, but in a way I can't fathom. I understand that svmono is non-standard, and I have also asked for help from the Springer staff, but no luck there (yet).

Any help further debugging the problem is much appreciated. I pored over the log file, also comparing the with successful compilation in TexLive 2017, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're using the syntax `\includegraphics[<stuff>]{<file>}` that requires that you load `graphicx` not `graphics`.

Comment: But we can't really use your MWE, as we don't have the files you're using (`svmono.cls` and `spbwftex-v4.sty` are not part of a normal TeX distribution). Also it would be better if you used `example-image` instead of an image that no one of us has.

Comment: If I use your MWE without the files we don't have, and add the missing definitions for the internals used inside `\SPIFIG` I get no error in TeX Live 2018 to 2021.

Comment: Thank you Skillmon. I edited to replace with graphicx, which leaves the problem unchanged (I had checked that already).  If you confirm that it works in TeX Live 2019 with a figure, then I have a problem with my installation, and will re-install.

Comment: I can't confirm anything, as I don't have your files, so didn't run your MWE. I just can say that I can't reproduce it from the information given. The issue might be in the class you're using, or in the package, or somewhere in your document. I have no idea.

Comment: I understand, Skillmon. I'd be happy to share the class and style files needed, but perhaps it is not worth it (and I don't know how to do that in Stack). Thank you for your comments!

Comment: I edited the question and made a MWE with a link to the necessary class and style files, asking that the question be reopened

Answer (score 0):

The Springer staff was able to solve this problem, so I thought I'd pass along the solution for anyone who might have the same problem.
This is the text of their email:

=======================

“graphics” package definitions are redefined for getting figure strips and it is not needed for final output pdf.

And these definitions does not have support in recent latex kernel.

So we removed the particular definitions and updated package attached here and will resolve the particular compilation error.

========================

They supplied a new spbwftex-v4.sty style file. I did a diff between the two versions (the old one that worked in TexLive 2017, and the new one) and there were 3 code blocks that seems to be relevant, and that needed to be commented out. Below I report the beginning of them:

< % \def\Gin@getbase#1{%
<   % \edef\Gin@tempa{%

< % \def\Ginclude@graphics##1{%
<   % \begingroup

< % \def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
<   % \begingroup

The file is also posted [here](https://www.bonamente-statistics-data-analysis.com/home/downloads)